# How do I create a Java Package and Test it Using Vim in Linux

Tags: java, linux, junit, package, classpath

I know how to create a java package, write code in the /src folder and test it from the /tst folder. But, I want to learn how I can do that without Eclipse, just using Vim.

For example, I have a java Hello World Class:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public void disp() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I save this in a directory home/javacode/HelloWorld

Now, I write a test for it in the same folder :

```
import org.junit.*;

class HelloWorldTest extends HelloWorld {
    @Test testHelloWorld() {
        HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
        hello.disp();
    }
}
```

Now, can someone please help me as to how to get this test to run? As in I have to compile Hello World as :

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

and then compile the test as :

```
javac -cp "path to junit" HelloWorldTest.java
```

However, I always end up with a ClassPath error. I understand that I am really messing up something very fundamental here. Please do help me out with this!

Comment: First of all, when you create a Test you use the class to be tested, you dont extends it.

Comment: can you tell what exactly is the classpath error? is it the classes in junit are not found or your classes are not found? Did you create your classes in a package?

Comment: No, there is no package. I literally just have HelloWorld and HelloWorldTest in the exact same folder. The CP error states that HelloWorld was not found. I want to learn how to do this exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile the test with:

```
javac -cp ".:path to junit" HelloWorldTest.java
```

Note the `.:` which means "current folder plus ..."

I'm pretty sure the current folder is not in the classpath by default for security reasons.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure the current folder is not in the classpath by default for security reasons."* - Erm, except that the default classpath is `"."`

Comment: I did : $ dpkg -L junit | grep junit.jar 
And got: /usr/share/java/junit.jar
         /usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar

Comment: And then, I did export CLASSPATH:CLASSPATH="usr/share/java/junit.jar"

Comment: What is `CLASSPATH:CLASSPATH` supposed to do?

Comment: @StephenC: Is the default classpath applied when you specify one with `-cp`? I think `-cp` replaces it instead.

Comment: @gran_profaci: Try `javac -cp ".:usr/share/java/junit.jar" HelloWorldTest.java`

Comment: Same error. Does it make a difference if I have import org.junit.* or junit.*

Comment: Yes, of course. I suggest that you try to make the code compile with Eclipse, to make sure it doesn't contain any obvious bugs. When you run the unit test in the IDE, you can get the classpath by selecting the Java process in the debug view (the process is the first child) and looking at it's properties (context menu -> properties).

Comment: @AaronDigulla - The "-cp" replaces the default classpath.  But my point is that if this was motivated by security, I'd have thought they wouldn't make the default classpath `"."`.  (This is not really analogous to putting `"."` on the command searchpath.)

Comment: @StephenC: My guess would be that it's either a "we can't create a classloader without a classpath" or a compatibility thing. But I'm pretty sure they don't always append the current folder to the classpath for security reasons and because classpaths are already confusing enough.